# Search all servers for service account

Tags: powershell

There has to be a better way

```
$server = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties *).name
foreach ($s in $server)

{
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter 'STARTNAME LIKE "%serviceaccount%"' -computername $s
}
```

I want to search all servers on the domain for a service account. The above kind of does what I'm looking for but it doesnt return what server the services account was found on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the G-WO object returned will contain the target system name. it is NOT displayed by default, so save one such to a $Var and use `Get-Member` on it to see what is _actually_ available. [*grin*]

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie to PS. Can you send me a snip of what your talking about?

Comment: As aside, don't use `-Properties *` to fetch ALL properties, especially since you are only interested in the `Name` attribute, which is returned by default anyway..

Comment: @user770022 - please take a look at my Answer for a demo of the idea. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

here's what i meant about using `Get-Member` to find the object properties that would give you the info you want. [*grin*]

this could be sped up considerably by giving the `G-WO` call a list of systems. i wasn't ready to code that just now. lazy ... [*blush*]

what it does ...

- sets the account to look for
  i only have the `LocalSystem` and `NetworkService` accounts listed on my services. [*grin*]
- sets the computer list to search
  you will likely use `Get-ADComputer`. make sure to *either* use the property name in the loop OR to make your query return only the actual name *value*.
  i only have one system, so my list is 3 different ways to get to the same computer.
- loops thru the systems
- call `G-WO` to get the service[s] that use the target account
- builds a `[PSCustomObect]` with the wanted properties
- sends that to the `$Result` collection
- shows that on screen

the code ...

```
$TargetAccount = 'LocalSystem'
$ComputerList = @(
    'LocalHost'
    '127.0.0.1'
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

$Result = foreach ($CL_Item in $ComputerList)
    {
    # i didn't want a gazillion services, so this uses array notation to grab the 1st item
    #    if you want all the items, remove the trailing "[0]"
    $GWMI_Result = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "STARTNAME LIKE '%$TargetAccount%'" -ComputerName $CL_Item)[0]

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $GWMI_Result.SystemName
        AccountName = $GWMI_Result.StartName
        ServiceName = $GWMI_Result.Name
        }
    }

$Result
```

output ...

```
ComputerName AccountName ServiceName                
------------ ----------- -----------                
MySysName    LocalSystem AMD External Events Utility
MySysName    LocalSystem AMD External Events Utility
MySysName    LocalSystem AMD External Events Utility
```